# How to use single quotes for XPath in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to pass an i value to fetch random selection check boxes with dynamic ids and the code is pasted below with the corresponding error message.

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'team_"+randNumber(i)+")]")) != null){
```

Error appears as:

```
The given selector //div[contains(@id,'team_'2)] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.
```

Thus the above term should has to display as `//div[contains(@id,'team_2')]`

Answer (score 1):

This has *nothing* to do with Selenium, this is *purely* a Java String manipulation problem!

```
int rand = randNumber(i);
String id = "team_" + rand;
String xpathh = "//div[contains(@id, '" + id + "']";    // note the nested quotes!
By.xpath(xpathh));
```

If you want to roll this into one line, copy pasting everything together yields:

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, '" + "team_" + randNumber(i) + "']"));
```

A couple of the quotes could be optimized out:

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'team_" + randNumber(i) + "']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'team_"+randNumber(i)+"')]")
```